# JForm error when creating a joomla component

Tags: php, joomla3.0, joomla-extensions

I'm new to joomla! extension development, and I'm developing a simple component,the idea of my component is to insert a couple of data into database. In the admin when people click on the new button it should enable them to insert values according to the form I created. Here is my problem when I click on the new button it show's me this error:
JForm::getInstance could not load file
So far i have created all the basic MVC model that the joomla! interface needs. Need help.
Thank you.(I'm using Joomla! version 3.0)

Answer (score 1):

That error is because joomla is not loading your form correctly. Can't say anything else without looking at the code, sorry.
If you want to see how a component works with a clean, functional written code, check http://component-creator.com. It creates a complete component with CRUD functions in 5-10 mins.

Regards,

Andrés